# RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference after login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have not been able to show the object created in the view, I give it the object but it appears null. I do not understand what is failing me, I have seen videos and it shows them the data in the view.

UserModel

```
namespace WebApplicationCleverHome.Models
{

    public class UserModel
    {

        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Welcome()
        {
            var data = DatabaseHandler.Run();
             
            foreach (var row in data)
            {
                ViewBag.UserModel = new UserModel
                {
                    Username = row.Username,
                    Password = row.Password
                };
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Welcome view:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Username: @ViewBag.UserModel.Username
    </div>
    <div>
        Password: @ViewBag.UserModel.Password
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null
> reference CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , object )
> System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1<T0, TRet>(CallSite
> site, T0 arg0) AspNetCore.Views_Login_Welcome.b__8_1()
> in Welcome.cshtml
> +
> Username: @ViewBag.UserModel.Username Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync()
> AspNetCore.Views_Login_Welcome.ExecuteAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage
> page, ViewContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage
> page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext
> viewContext, string contentType, Nullable statusCode)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext
> viewContext, string contentType, Nullable statusCode)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
> actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData,
> ITempDataDictionary tempData, string contentType, Nullable
> statusCode)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
> context, ViewResult result)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|29_0<TFilter,
> TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next,
> Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter,
> TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref
> bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool
> isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State
> next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

**AspNetCore.Views_Login_Welcome.ExecuteAsync()**

Comment: Where does it say null? Can you post the full error you got?

Comment: @j3st that error appears to me when the view is not the first one seen on the page. The error appears to me when I see that page after login.